# Xubuntu 15.04 internet connection problems

Tags: networking, wireless, xubuntu, internet, 15.04

I just installed Xubuntu 15.04 on my computer and I cannot log onto the Internet. My computer was connected during installation via ethernet. Once Xubuntu 15.04 had installed, I wasn't able to connect to the Internet. I would like to be able to connect via ethernet and also via my Broadcom Corp. BCM4401-B00 wireless LAN. What steps do I need to take to get my computer online? It's a Dell Vostro 1500.

I typed that command prompt in and here's the output:

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation BCM 4401-B0 100 Base-TX [14e4:170c] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0228] 03:01.0
FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller [1 180:0832] (rev 05)
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev05)
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM 4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1390 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:0007}
Kernel driver in use:wl
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | egrep 'Eth|Net' -A2` terminal command.

Comment: I typed the command promt in and listed the output in my original post. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Your wl wireless driver has blacklisted your ethernet driver due to a bug in Broadcom installation script.

You can get your Ethernet working by

```
 sudo modprobe b44
```

Yo make it permanent you need to run

```
sudo sed -i -e '/blacklist b44/d' -e '$ c install wl modprobe -r b43 b43legacy ssb; modprobe --ignore-install wl' /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf
```

Comment: That worked for a while but I was still not able to use my wireless LAN. I added another Broadcom package and now I can't use my ethernet either. Actually, I don't care about the ethernet because I'm planning on just using the wireless. How do I get the wireless LAN working?

Comment: @Mark I think you need to ask another question with output of `lspci -knn | grep -E 'Eth|Net' -A2.

Comment: How can I get my wireless LAN working? I imputed the command above and the output is as follows: 03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX [14e4:170c] (rev 02) Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0228] 03:01.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 IEEE 1394 Controller [1180:0832] (rev 05) 0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01) Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1390 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:0007] Kernel driver in use: wl

Answer (score 0):

Well now I feel kind of stupid. I swear I already tried this (been trying for three days) but running sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-sourse and the running the sudo apt-get linux-firmware-nonfree got it. Once these were complete I rebooted and there was the wifi connections. Thank you all for your interest.