# Ubuntu 14.04 64bit No Wifi

Tags: 14.04, wireless

Every time I activate the Broadcom wifi driver my ethernet stops working and I still don't have wifi. I have to use Sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source and restart to get the ethernet back. Any ideas? I have a Dell Inspiron 1501.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep -EA2 Eth|Net` terminal command.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/a/640245/167850